# zlib can't be found by make

Tags: docker, makefile, zlib, archlinux

I wanted to compile RetroArch for my Wii U but after I did `make -j6 -f Makefile.wiiu`, I got this error:

```
make: *** [Makefile.wiiu:302: objs/wiiu/./libretro-common/streams/trans_stream_zlib.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
libretro-common/file/archive_file_zlib.c:34:10: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
   34 | #include <zlib.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile.wiiu:302: objs/wiiu/./libretro-common/file/archive_file_zlib.o] Error 1
```

I already installed zlib with pacman

Comment: It is not a make problem. It is your compiler that issues the error because you include `<zlib.h>` but it didn't find this header file. Look at your compiler options and make sure you pass the correct location for `zlib.h`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I already fixed the issue by using a Docker container with Arch and pacman.